# C# Trigger delayed job only once per ID

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to execute some jobs in C# but after a given time interval for a specific entity in our database with a specific ID.

If another subsequent job is scheduled to be executed for the same ID but another job for the same ID has already been scheduled then that job should be discarded and only the previous job should be executed after the delay has expired.

Any ways to do this?

Comment: Please provide more information regarding what you're using to schedule said jobs

Comment: Use a HashSet<T> to hold your list of jobs to be executed? That should limit you to a single instance.